# Google App Domain redirect

Tags: dns

I've buyed 2 domanins from google: xyz.com and xyz.net.
I don't want to manage 2 different app domains but use them as alias.
I want that xyz.net redirect to xyz.com but I cannot create an alias because xyz.com is already in use (google create an app also for both).
I cannot cancel an account because I've registered the domain with google... The DNS table are the same for both domains.
What can I do?

Comment: Google is not a registrar, so you bought the domain from somewhere else, where you can presumably change the DNS settings or set up forwarding.  And what do you mean by Google "creating an app"?  Are you using App Engine?  Google certainly doesn't create applications for you, even when you sign up for a domain.  (This question probably is off-topic as well, as it's not programming related).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for aswering! I've just noticed that google registered the domain with enom.com and I can access the domain settings on enom console. I'm using "Google Apps" see here: https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/domain/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear as mud.

As pointed out, Google is not a registrar. You must've bought it from somewhere like Go Daddy.

But the other part of your comment makes even less sense. If you purchased xyz.com, then you can control that domain and where it redirects to. So what do you mean when you say it's already in use?

To redirect a domain, registrars like Go Daddy have a feature in the domain manager to perform a permanent redirect. Or you can easily accomplish the same thing from most website development tools like ASP.NET.

Comment: I've add an new host record of type "URL Redirect" from www.xyz.com to www.xyz.net and it works